# Favicon not working

Tags: html, favicon

My favicon that I am trying to insert into my webpage is not working. Can someone tell me the code and styling I need to insert it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Crash - Login or Signup</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="crash_styling.css"></link>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">      
    </head> 

    <body  link="#336666" alink="red" vlink="red">

        <div id="header_title">
            <h1 id="title">crash</h1>
            <p id="motto">Keep track of all your assignments and projects.</p>
        </div>  

        <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get" id="user_passEntry">
            Username:<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Username" /> <br />
            Password:<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

        <p id="description">Crash is a way students can keep track of their projects and assignments on the computer or on their devices. With crash, you can be sure you'll never turn in something late again.</p>

                <div class="make"><a href="crash_styling" style="text-decoration:none"/>Make a New Assignment</div>
                <div class="edit"><a href="crash_styling" style="text-decoration:none"/>Edit an Assignment</div>
                <div class="check"><a href="crash_styling" style="text-decoration:none"/>Check off an Assignment</div>
    </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: html. just the tag you use to insert the favicon.

Comment: HTML of course, CSS does not have anything in common

Comment: Are you sure that you have to use absolute path `href="/favicon.ico"` instead of `href="favicon.ico"` **?**

Comment: @Teneff Talking about this 'absolute path', what does that mean? What does the `/` do here?

Comment: @poepje it means that if you're browsing subfolder like `http://localhost/a/b/c/d/e/` the relative path will look for `http://localhost/a/b/c/d/e/favicon.ico` and the absolute for `http://localhost/favicon.ico`

Comment: I don't quite get it yet. There is nothing before the `/`. If it would say `somefolder/favicon.ico` or `../favicon.ico` I would understand, but this?

Comment: @poepje Starting the path with `/` means "the rest of this path starts from the root directory", just as starting a path with `..` means "the rest of this path starts from the parent of the current directory".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To place a Favicon on your site you would use the following in the `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://yourwebsitepath/favicon.ico" />
```

You need to be sure that the path is correct for the icon. If the path is not correct it will not appear.  I have also seen caching issues that makes it seem that the icon isn't working.  Always try to restart your browser after clearing the cache.

Comment: it works when using the absolute url, but not for when working from a local host out of my project folder

Comment: Thanks!! For me it was probably the cache. This should be documented somewhere!!!! Very hard to figure out unless someone knows its the cache. :)

Comment: For me, in localhost on Chrome, even in Incognito the favicon won't show. Then, I tested on firefox and it works.

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes [forced reload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) (additional Wikipedia information in this link) fixes the problem. You need to reload the browser's caché memory.

- Firefox: ctrl + shift + R
- Chrome: ctrl + right click on Chrome's reload button
- Edge: Same as Chrome, or ctrl + F5

Other combinations can be found in the above provided link.

Comment: Ctrl + right click on reload button for Chrome worked for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you have a *bad path* to your *icon*. Confirm your *file path*. 
Try to use

```
href="favicon.ico"
```

instead of

```
href="/favicon.ico"
```

maybe it will work. Or if you have icon in some *folder* for example in *images*

```
href="images/favicon.ico"
```

You doing it right but if you will have *bad path*, *icon* won't appear.

So your `CSS` works and if your *icon* is on *same level* like `CSS` file so remove `/` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

If using Chrome: clear the cache, close Chrome, and restart. It is what helped me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make an PNG file
2. Set it as the favicon in an index.html page so the cache is overwritten:

It works.