# How to update a static webpage which is already publish on Github?

Tags: reactjs, git, updates, github-pages, publish

I want to update/change my existing published static web page on Github. I work on Reactjs.
How do I do this?

I already pushed the code on Github. but when I open the published link it shows the old version of it.

Comment: has the Github page action any errors?

Comment: You may need to force-reload the page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67077128/7389293

Answer (score 0):

Github pages might take around 10 minutes to be updated.
If you have edited the exact page file, then it should be updated within the time. And it might take lesser time.
And after all you can track your Github Pages building, and when are **ticked**, it means they are ready at the their location, weather "`abc.github.io/index.html`" or "`abc.github.io/index`" or both.[image: Github page ready]
**Note**:Try adding a "`.html`" extension in the address bar, if you do not see any changes, and vice-versa. But after a while, both the pages will be ready.